# SymPy, how to perform exact symbolic representation (Rational Issue)?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-computation

So I'm planning to write a web application about math, and I need to convert user input to a SymPy expression without modifying it (Simplification), eg. so I'd like to cancel this behaviour like in this example.

```
>>> srepr(Rational(2,4)) #this is the problem
'Rational(1, 2)'

>>> srepr(Rational(2,4,evaluate=False)) #doesn't work
Traceback...
```

But I've managed to do it in other types of representations.

```
>>> srepr(Pow(x,(Mul(e,e,evaluate=False)),evaluate=False)) #nice
"Pow(Symbol('x'), Mul(Symbol('e'), Symbol('e')))"

>>> srepr(sqrt(Integer(8))) #not what I want
'Mul(Integer(2), Pow(Integer(2), Rational(1, 2)))'

>>> srepr(Pow(Integer(8),Rational(1,2),evaluate=False)) #this is the way
'Pow(Integer(8), Rational(1, 2))'

>>> from sympy import E
>>> log(E,evaluate=False)
log(E)
```

Also isn't there a way to tell SymPy that *all representations* shouldn't be evaluated?

Comment: What are you using sympy for in your application? What are you doing with the sympy objects after they are created? Why don't you want sympy to simplify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
>>> S('2/4',evaluate=False)
2/4
>>> srepr(_)
'Mul(Integer(2), Pow(Integer(4), Integer(-1)))'
```

Comment: I rewrote the __new__ method for the Rational class and I got the expected behaviour anyway, now supports evaluate as flag, which is much more convenient. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Edward that's a useful feature. We'd accept a pull request implementing it.

Comment: @asmeurer well it's not a big deal, quite a simple modification, I'll pull a request soon then, I was trying to design an educational system based on sympy, so I didn't want to change Rational(4,2) to Integer(2) because then "students" may have no idea what happened, but I gave up as my current economical situations in my country won't allow me to design such project.